# How can I allow other image formats to be uploaded

Tags: php

This is the code that uploads users logo's I was wondering if anyone could help me.
I want to be able to allow users to upload .png and .gif files too.

Sorry if this is a simple fix but I am very new to php.

```
<?
//edit logo

function resize_image ($image) {
    $imgsize = getimagesize($image);
    //check for gallery type to determine thumbnail size

    $size_x = 150;      
    $ratio = 150 / $imgsize[0];
    $size_y = $imgsize[1] * $ratio;


    $srcimage         = ImageCreateFromjpeg ($image);
    $newimage         = ImageCreateTrueColor($size_x,$size_y);  
    //$newimage        = imagecreate ($size_x, $size_y);
    imagecopyresized ($newimage, $srcimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size_x, $size_y,
    imagesx($srcimage), imagesy($srcimage));
    return $newimage;
}

$myrepairer = new repairer;


//resize and upload image

$file =  $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];
$file_name =  $_FILES['logo']['name'];

//upload the image followed by a db update.
if ($file != 'none') {
if (copy($file,'logos/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.jpg')) {
    unlink($file);
}
$myrepairer->updatelogo($_REQUEST['id'],$_REQUEST['id']);   
$thumbnail = resize_image('logos/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.jpg');
unlink('logos/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.jpg');
ImageJPEG($thumbnail,'logos/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.jpg');
}

$resultmessage = '<div align="center" class="GreenText">Logo Updated</div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the file extension and use it instead of '.jpg'.

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['logo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

So, it'll be something like:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['logo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//upload the image followed by a db update.
if ($file != 'none') {
if (copy($file,'logos/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.'.$ext)) {
    unlink($file);
}
$myrepairer->updatelogo($_REQUEST['id'],$_REQUEST['id']);   
$thumbnail = resize_image('logos/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.'.$ext);
unlink('logos/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.'.$ext);
ImageJPEG($thumbnail,'logos/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.'.$ext);
```

Comment: Okay I added that and I now get this error.                                             No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Comment: Check if your HTML form action has enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute:

<form action="post.php"
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  File: <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>